# How to modify the available filter operators of a smart table

Tags: sapui5

I have a smart table that shows data from odata service. all properties of the entity type are Edm.String.

now i can set a filter for each column of the resulting table with a lot of filter operators.

My goal is to filter the list of available filter operators depending on the selected column.

e.g.
selected colum 'A' then allow only 'equal to'.

Is that somehow possible? I would like to solve it in front end code.

I didn't find anything like that in ui5 docu...

EDIT:
i want to reduce this list in the red box (sample: https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `equals` FilterOperator
here is a link for  [FilterOperator](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator%23properties) and another example how to use filter in grid table [https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Filtering)

Here is a quick example of setting more than one filter each with different Filter Operator

```
filterGlobally : function(oEvent) {
    var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
    this._oGlobalFilter = null;

    if (sQuery) {          
        this._oGlobalFilter = new Filter([
            new Filter("columA", FilterOperator.EQ, sQuery),        
            new Filter("columB", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery) 
        ], false);
    }
    var oFilter = null;
    if (this._oGlobalFilter) {
        oFilter = new Filter([this._oGlobalFilter], true);
    } 
    this.byId("idTable").getBinding().filter(oFilter, "Application");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am not sure how your proposal relates to my question so i tried to point out what i want to achieve with a screenshot.